# Печать одной страницы из другой

Tags: html, печать, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток господа.

Есть страница 1, на которую хочу поместить кнопку: печать страницы. Но не текущей, а страницы 2. Конечно как вариант iframe 8-))) Но не хочу, что бы на странице 2 были какие то дополнительные кнопки.

Подскажите, как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть специальный плагин - jquery.printPage.js
Он позволяет печатать страницы по URL:

```
<a class="btnPrint" href='page2.html'>Печатать вторую страницу!</a>
<script>$(".btnPrint").printPage();</script>
```

Comment: веселая штука. правда если очень резко нажимать печать и отмена раз так 5ть - во всех 5ти браузерах вылетает и тушит браузер. не подскажите есть ли такое же решение, но без картинки в центре? (из за нее вылетает)

Comment: вылетает скорее всего из-за путаницы в создаваемых iFrame. Картинку можно убрать руками, изменив функцию loadPrintDocument на addIframeToPage(el, pluginOptions); удалив остальные строки.

Comment: iframe - всего один. всю функцию изменил, к сожалению не сработало. как быть?

    function loadPrintDocument(el, pluginOptions){
      addIframeToPage(el, pluginOptions);
    }

за ответ спасибо, но решение только для использования без стилей (удалось напечатать только буквы без всего остального)

Answer (score 2):

Подключаем CSS распечатки

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

В нем, например, пишем что-то типа

```
*{display:none;}
#toPrint {display:block;}
```

display `#toPrint` в основном css'e, естественно, `none`

Например есть кнопка вида

```
<button class="printPage" data-src="/some/path/to/some/htmlPage.html">распечатать  htmlPage</button>
```

JS код будет иметь примерно такой вид:

```
$('.printPage').on('click', function() {
  $.get( $(this).data('src'), function( html ) {
    $('#toPrint').html( html );
    print();
  });
});
```

Это на вскидку, особо не раздумывая, естественно, если мы делаем запрос целой html страницы, то нам нужно будет еще из html'я, который мы получили после запроса, убрать head, doctype, script теги и т.д., но это, теоретически, не обязательно, в любом случае - мне писать лениво

Comment: кнопку попробую. так наверно будет правильнее